# Is there a polynomial time algorithm determine whether a given point $x$ is a basic feasible solution(vertex solution) of polyhedron $P$

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Given a polyhedron $P \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ defined by $m$ inequalites $Ax \leq b$. Given a point $z \in \mathbb{R^n}$, is there a polynomial time algorithm to determine if $z$ is a basic feasible solution(vertex solution) of $P$?

Comment: what does the question have to do with graph theory or algorithms?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just compute $Az.$ If it is equal to $b,$ then check how many constraints are violated for $z + \epsilon A_i$ (where $A_i$ is the $i$-th row.)

Comment: Can I proceed in the following way: suppose $rank(A) = m$, if there are $> n-m$ zeros in $z$, then the solution is degenerate. If there are $< n-m$ zeros in $z$, then the solution is not basic. Now, the only case left is exactly $n-m$ zeros in $z$, then we can just compute $Az$ to check if it's equal to $b$. Is my algorithm correct?

Comment: Igor, I just want to make sure if $m$ constraints are violated for $z + \epsilon A_i$, does that mean it is  a vertex solution? Otherwise, if it violated $<m$ of them, then it's not a vertex solution

Comment: This answer is quite vague and could use some sort of explanation as to why the procedure works.